# If div is empty, set the container div to "display:none"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, api

I've been trying to get this code to work for the past day whilst searching through these forums but without any success.

I'm looking to hide a container `div` if one of the `div`'s inside has no content.

The script I've got is below:

```
$('.video-centre').each(function(){
  if ($(this).find('.video-thumb p').text().length == "")
    $(this).find('.video-centre').css("display", "none");

});
```

The HTML that I'm trying to apply this to is below:

```
<div class="video-centre">
  <div class="video-point">
    <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/video-point.jpg" alt="video pointer" />
  </div>
  <div class="video-thumb">
    <?php the_field('testimonials'); ?>
  </div>
  <p class="video-more">
    <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.show(['expandable-1'])">View More</a>
  </p>
  <div id="expandable-1">
    <div class="video-thumb">
      <?php the_field('testimonials_hidden'); ?>
    </div>
    <p class="video-close">
      <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.hide(['expandable-1'])">Close</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, within wordpress, the client will have the opportunity to add videos, it's a bit long winded but they get wrapped in `p` tags. However if they don't upload anything to a specific area, I would like the container `div` to have `display:none`, resulting in only containers being shown if videos have been uploaded.

If there's an easier way to look at the `div` and say if it's empty then get container `div` to display none I'd be happy to try that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:empty` pseudoclass

```
if ($(this).find('.video-thumb p').is(':empty'))
```

this checks if you have an empty paragraph (`<p></p>`), while

```
if ($(this).find('.video-thumb').is(':empty'))
```

checks an empty `.video-thumb` element

---

After your edit: if you have spaces inside div the condition return false so it's better to simple check

```
if ($(this).find('.video-thumb p').length === 0)
```

Example Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6nyF8/6/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've just added this in but without any success.
Looking at the console, I can't see any conflicts with other js files hence the confusion about why it's not working.

Comment: please post a fiddle with your attempts and update the question with a link

Comment: Just added a fiddle link, I've added 2 containers, one with content and one without to work on and as you can see the script doesn't want to work

Comment: 1) you have to choose the jQuery library in the fiddle :) (not mootools) 2) `empty` return false if you have spaces inside the element 3) In your specific case it's better to check if you have a paragraph or not, so see my next update

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to fiddle so didn't realise. 
I've updated the fiddle with the new library and without any spaces in the specific div. http://jsfiddle.net/6nyF8/7/

Comment: :) thanks for that...but.....
would you know why it won't work on the actual site?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in several ways.

```
$('.video-centre').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('div.video-thumb').html('') == '')
      $(this).hide();
});
```

OR

```
$('.video-centre').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('div.video-thumb').children().length == 0)
      $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).find('.video-thumb p').text() == "")
```

or

```
if ($(this).find('.video-thumb p').is(':empty'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand the Q, here's the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3yfm/5/)** I came up with. Nice and simple.

```
if ($('.video-centre').find('div:hidden').size() > 0) {
    $('.video-centre').children().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try remowing line feeds between html tags and

```
<div class="video-thumb">
<?php the_field('testimonials'); ?>
</div>
```

should be

```
<div class="video-thumb"><?php the_field('testimonials'); ?></div>
```

but you could also do the trick in PHP:

```
<?php if (the_field('testimonials')=="") $style=" style='display:none'";?>
<div class="video-thumb" <?php print $style;?>>
<?php the_field('testimonials'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The php worked..kind of...
It only removed the video-thumb div, whilst I need the video-centre div to disappear if no content is apparent. Also, when adding to the other containers in the page, it get's rid of the div even if there is content present.

Comment: Ok, i see, in that case put the first line (<?php if (the_field... at the beginning of the html so that it all becames:
<?php if (the_field('testimonials')=="") $style=" style='display:none'";?>
<div class="video-centre" <?php print $style ?>>

Answer (score 0):

You can also check string with striptags function so from your "testimonials" value remove tags using php in built function "striptags" so now only text will remain which can be compare easily.